# Add an autoincrementing ID column to an existing table with Sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Using Sqlite, I want to add an auto-incrementing ID column to an existing table which had previously no ID:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = db.cursor()

c.execute('create table events (int weight, text str)')
c.execute('insert into events values(?, ?)', (1371, 'Test1'))
c.execute('insert into events values(?, ?)', (223, 'Test2'))
c.execute('select * from events'); print c.fetchall()
# [(1371, u'Test1'), (223, u'Test2')]

# add an autoincrementing ID to existing table
c.execute('alter table events add id int not null auto_increment primary key')
```

**How to do it properly?** I have this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "auto_increment": syntax error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An SQLite table cannot modified in a significant manner using alter table once it has been created. One common popular suggestion is to create a new table with the existing fields as well as the additionally required field and copy/import your data into the new one and optionally delete the old one.

```
c.execute('create table events_copy(id integer primary key autoincrement, weight integer,str text)')
c.execute('insert into events_copy(weight, str) select weight, str from events')
c.execute('drop table events')
c.execute('alter table events_copy rename to events')
c.commit()
```

Comment: If the table with the large amount of rows (as my > 1 mln) use `VACUUM` statement in order get rid of cache.

Comment: Note that most tables in sqlite automatically include an internal column `rowid` that holds an integer primary key which is likely sufficient for your purposes. The `rowid` column is unique for records in the table (but may be reused if records are deleted). More info: https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Answer (score -3):

It's a easy solution bro just use ''AUTOINCREMENT'' instead of ''AUTO_INCREMENT''